# what does the application/vnd.google-apps.file mime stand for?

Tags: api, mime, drive

What on earth does application/vnd.google-apps.file mime represent ? It's definitelly not any file and it's definitelly not GSuite file !

I tried all other mime types from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types and they return something but that one returns... NOTHING ! So how could I know what it returns ? And why doesn't google document that ?? Just saying "Google Drive file" doesn't mean much without concrete examples !

I am using Drive API 3 with file.list endpoint. 
All these work:

```
application/vnd.google-apps.folder, 
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet,
application/vnd.google-apps.drawing,
application/vnd.google-apps.form,
```

So why does the file one return nothing ?? Should file mean all of these: spreadsheet, drawing etc ?

Comment: This MIME type is simply a file, which could hold a text file or any other type of data not automatically prescribed by the other specific MIME types.

Comment: @JimGrant thanks for reply. Any idea then why it doesn't return anything while all the others do ? I have plenty of text files in My Drive ..